# Browser is not sending requests (CORS configuration)

Tags: angular, cors

I've digged a bit more into CORS configuration. Browser tries to ask for a valid request configuration sending a CORS request before sending the `"real"` request. My server app has configured a `CORSFilter` and it's already responding to these requests. Nevertheless, the response is an `200 - OK` code but the `"real"` request is not sent.

As far I've been able to figure out, when `CORS request` is `200-OK` then browser should have to send the `"real"` request, should,n't it?

When I reach `this.http.request(path, requestOptions)` a CORS request is sent:

`curl "http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng/users" -X OPTIONS -H "Host: localhost:8082" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" --compressed -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: passwd,user" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" -H "Connection: keep-alive"`

and response headers:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Server: WildFly/10
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 07:50:55 GMT
Allow: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 23
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1209600`

Is there any issue I don't understand?

Why browser is not sending `"real"` request?

**EDIT**

This chain starts when I'm trying to send a `PUT` request (typescript fragemnt code):

```
/**
     * User exists
     * 
     * @param user username
     */
    public existsWithHttpInfo(user: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<Response> {
        const path = this.basePath + `/users`;

        let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845
        // verify required parameter 'user' is not null or undefined
        if (user === null || user === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter user was null or undefined when calling exists.');
        }

        headers.set('user', String(user));

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
        ];

        // to determine the Accept header
        let produces: string[] = [
            'application/json'
        ];





        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            headers: headers,
            search: queryParameters
        });

        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = this.extendObj(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
    }
```

CorsFilter:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {   
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

[image]

**Error Message**

```
Object {
  _body: error,
  status: 0,
  ok: false,
  statusText: "",
  headers: Object,
  type: 3,
  url: null
}
```

Comment: I've added on post a error message I missed. Could you take a look on this message.

Comment: Where do you get this error message? If this is in the browser console I'm sure there is some context added as well.

Comment: This is the output of `this.http.request(path, requestOptions).map((response: Response) => { return response.json(); }).subscribe((error: any) => {console.log(error);});`

Comment: That doesn't look like an error, that looks like a normal response. This way you can distinguish between error and normal result `this.http.request(path, requestOptions).map((response: Response) => { return response.json(); }).subscribe((result) => { console.log('result:', result);}, (error: any) => {console.log('error:', error);});`

Comment: To me it looks like what you posted as error is the response from the server received normally by Angular.

Comment: From this message I'm figuring out something in wrnong, isn't it? Could you guess what's wrong? What does `type: "3"` mean?

Comment: If you actually got it from the code you posted in your last comment, it's what the server sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using:

`responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");`

you are not allowed to use the wildcard for origin. Change it to:

`responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "my.frontend.com");`

Comment: Browser sends an `OPTIONS` request first. Your backend responds to that and in the response you add the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "my.frontend.com"` (and others). The browser then checks the headers of the `OPTIONS` response, that is how it knows what it is allowed to send. So this results in you only getting requests from the 'my.frontend.com' which you yourself explicitly allow when responding to the `OPTIONS` request in your backend.